# What is a good site for checking out color schemes for websites with examples

Tags: css

For instance you chose X,Y and Z colors, and then websites shows you a sort of "Ipsum Lorem" website using your chosen colors.

What do you personally use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out

[Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

There is an option for Light Page Example which shows a small preview for the colors in a web page.

Answer (score 1):

[Colourlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/) is particularly good, I find.

Answer (score 1):

http://kuler.adobe.com/ is cool

Comment: This isn't your responsibility, but "kuler requires the latest version of the Adobe Flash Player." The offered download seems to be the already-installed version. FF3.0.13, Ubuntu 8.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I love the way browsershots.org does it... give that a try.